# Creating a method in Ruby that takes in an array and returns a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would you solve this problem in Ruby. "Define a method called yeller that takes in an array of characters and returns a string with an ALLCAPS version of the input. Verify that yeller([’o’, ’l’, ’d’]) returns "OLD". Combine the .join, .map, .upcase methods."

So far I have:

```
def yeller(x) 
  x.map do |y|  
  y.upcase.join     
    puts y
  end
end
yeller(['o', 'l', 'd'])
```

Comment: Another note, in ruby you can also do `%w(o l d)` instead of `['o', 'l', 'd']`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
def yeller(x)
  imsupercool = x.map do |y|
    y.upcase
  end
   imsupercool.join
end
puts yeller(['o', 'l', 'd'])
```

Comment: "Define a method called yeller that takes in an array of characters and returns a string(...)" . This returns `nil` (because `puts` returns nil).

Comment: remove the `puts` from the method definition and use `puts` before calling the function i.e. `puts yeller(['o','l','d'])`

Answer (score 7):

It's so simple

```
def yeller(x)
  x.join.upcase
end

yeller(['o', 'l', 'd'])
 => "OLD"
```

`join` makes your character list a string and `upcase` makes that string uppercase

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer from the textbook where you got the question from.

```
def yeller(chars)
  chars.map(&:upcase).join
end
yeller(['o', 'l', 'd'])
=> "OLD"
```